# Create a view block on a node reference field (using Node Reference)

Tags: nodes

Creating a related content block on a node reference field. I have two content types: **Article and Author**.

The content type Article has the field Label: Por 'field_autor' which is a node reference to an author node.

I want to be able to take that ID and lis other articles with the same NID.

**The view is setup as such:**

- Format: HTML List
- Fields: Title
- Filter: Published;
- Type (Article)
- Order: Weight

Advanced Options

- Contextual Filters: (field_autor) Content: Nid
- Relationships: Content: Por (field_autor) - reverse

However, this isn't displaying articles with the same author. Looking for assistance!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

There are some decent explanations on the internet

1. http://www.webomelette.com/related-content-block-views-drupal-7
2. http://www.webomelette.com/related-content-views-taxonomy-drupal

As well the eva module was suggested as being helpful in my situation, but I haven't tried it yet

Currently, this is still an issue for me.